# Why is my Video played in simulator but not on Device (iPad) using AVFoundation Videoplayer?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios5, ios-simulator, avfoundation

I built my own custom video player (edit: [find example code here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2896178/AVFoundationVideoPLayer.zip)) with

AVMoviePlayerView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@class AVPlayer;

@interface AVMoviePlayerView : UIView

@property (nonatomic) AVPlayer *player;

- (void)setPlayer:(AVPlayer*)player;
- (void)setVideoFillMode:(NSString *)fillMode;

@end
```

and

AVMoviePlayerView.m

```
#import "AVMoviePlayerView.h"
#import <CoreMedia/CoreMedia.h>

@implementation AVMoviePlayerView


+ (Class)layerClass {

    return [AVPlayerLayer class];

}

- (AVPlayer*)player
{
    return [(AVPlayerLayer*)[self layer] player];
}

- (void)setPlayer:(AVPlayer*)player
{
    [(AVPlayerLayer*)[self layer] setPlayer:player];
}

- (void)setVideoFillMode:(NSString *)fillMode
{
    AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = (AVPlayerLayer*)[self layer];
    playerLayer.videoGravity = fillMode;
}


@end
```

calling it from inside my MainViewController.m within -(void)viewDidLoad

```
    NSURL* url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"myVideo.264" withExtension:@"mp4"]; 
    self.avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
    [avPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:AVMoviePlayerViewControllerStatusObservationContext];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]   addObserver:self
                                               selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                                   name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                                 object:[self.avPlayer currentItem]];
```

with methods

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString*) path ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary*)change context:(void*)context
{
    if (avPlayer.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
        [self.VideoLoop setPlayer:self.avPlayer];
        [self.avPlayer play];
    }
}
- (void)playerItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification *)notification {
    AVPlayerItem *p = [notification object];
    [p seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
}
```

and of course defined in MainViewController.h

```
...
#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>
#import "AVMoviePlayerView.h"
@class AVMoviePlayerView;
@class AVPlayer;
...
IBOutlet AVMoviePlayerView *VideoLoop;
AVPlayer* avPlayer;
```

It works fine in Simulator (except the loop, but thats a different problem) but on the device (iPad3) no video shows up.

Did I miss anything?
Thanx!!!

EDIT: [TO make it easier toshow me how stupid I am please find here some esample code. this does work in the simulator but not on device.](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2896178/AVFoundationVideoPLayer.zip)

Comment: funny: using NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.samkeeneinteractivedesign.com/videos/littleVid3.mp4"]; works on iPad. hm...

Comment: looks to me like in some cases the path to the video file isn't found on the device but found on the simulator.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Reason found - costs me only 50 points...
iOS supports MPEG-4 video up to 2.5 Mbps, and H.264 1080p. My video frame size was too big!

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to @headkit's answer, which did the trick for me...

Open your video file in QuickTime,

Export > 1080p.

Dont forget to change the extension to "mov"!!

Comment: better put this into the answer as comment and delete this answer as this problem is solved already.

Comment: Thanks so much omg, the accepted answer explain the issue and hinted at fix, but this really told me what to do step by step!

Answer (score 0):

For others that comes here like me and wants updated specs [from Apple docs](https://www.apple.com/iphone-6s/specs/):

**iPhone 7, 6s**

> Video formats supported: H.264 video up to 4K, 30 frames per second,
>   High Profile level 4.2 with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48kHz, stereo
>   audio in .m4v, .mp4 and .mov file formats; MPEG-4 video up to
>   2.5 Mbps, 640x480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Simple Profile with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps per channel, 48kHz, stereo audio in .m4v,
>   .mp4 and .mov file formats; Motion JPEG (M-JPEG) up to 35 Mbps,
>   1280x720 pixels, 30 frames per second, audio in ulaw, PCM stereo audio
>   in .avi file format

**iPhone 5, 5s, 6**

> Video formats supported: H.264 video up to 1080p, 30 frames per
>   second, High Profile level 4.1 with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps,
>   48kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats; MPEG-4 video
>   up to 2.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Simple
>   Profile with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps per channel, 48kHz, stereo
>   audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats; Motion JPEG (M-JPEG) up to
>   35 Mbps, 1280 by 720 pixels, 30 frames per second, audio in ulaw, PCM
>   stereo audio in .avi file format

(For updated links search in google ***iPhone (model number) specs*** and tap on the result from Apple site. Than scroll down to "video playback")