# Mp4 file cannot play

Tags: ios, objective-c, video

I have a `splash_screen.mp4` file.

Here is my code in `.h` file

```
@property AVPlayer * player;
@property AVPlayerLayer * playerLayer;
```

in `.m` file:

```
NSURL* mURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"splash_screen" withExtension:@"mp4"];

self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:mURL];
self.player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
Float64 seconds = 1.5f;
CMTime targetTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(seconds, NSEC_PER_SEC);
[self.player seekToTime:targetTime];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                                 name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                               object:[self.player currentItem]];

self.playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.player];
self.playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
self.playerLayer.needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = YES;
[self.playerLayer setFrame:[self.view bounds]];

[self.view.layer addSublayer:self.playerLayer];
self.view.layer.needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = YES;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
        if (self.player) {
            [self.player play];
        }
    });
```

In the past, I had a .mov file and could play video file, but now I have a .mp4 file and can not play it.

Tested on simulator, the video is run, but on device, it is not run.

Comment: It works for me. When you play the .mp4 file, app crashes or not? If it crashes, what's the output in the console?

Comment: @ronan, it doesn't crash. just white blank screen. I debug and can get the url, but I don't know why video can not be played.

Comment: check, it copied in copy bundle resource properly.

Comment: @rohitSidpara, I checked, it presents on bundle resource, that's why I can get url.

Comment: I'm using your code to build a new project. It can play in both simulator and device. I call the code in viewDidLoad. put your debug output of the url

Comment: visit this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12071668/why-is-my-video-played-in-simulator-but-not-on-device-ipad-using-avfoundation

Comment: @rohitSidpara, yes, work on iPhone 6 plus, not work on iPhone5, 5s.

Comment: try another low resolution mp4 file, i think it will working in 5 and 5s also

Comment: @rohitSidpara, thanks, your solution help me :)

Comment: i think you have to use MPMoviePlayerController for play video

Answer (score 0):

You need to  select "Target Membership" in the right hand panel for your mp4 file.

1. select MP4 file

2 . see screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I have check all target membership

Comment: It is not affected.

Comment: Tested on simulator, it run. But on device, it doesn't :(.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works

```
Asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]];
avPlayerItem =[[AVPlayerItem alloc]initWithAsset:Asset];
avPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithPlayerItem:avPlayerItem];
avPlayerLayer =[AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:Player];
[avPlayerLayer setFrame:self.view.frame];
[self.view.layer addSublayer:avPlayerLayer];
[avPlayer seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
[avPlayer play];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with adding observer on it with handling it in Try & Catch.

please enable "App plays audio or streams audio/video using AirPlay " in Required background modes.

```
    NSURL* mURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"splash_screen" withExtension:@"mp4"];

    NSURL *url = mURL;
        AVPlayer *player = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithURL:url];
        if (_audioPlayer != nil)
        {
            @try {
                [_audioPlayer removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" context:nil];
            } @catch (NSException *exception) {
                NSLog(@"Catch player exception");
            }
        }
        _audioPlayer = player; 
self.playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player];
self.playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
self.playerLayer.needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = YES;
[self.playerLayer setFrame:[self.view bounds]];

[self.view.layer addSublayer:self.playerLayer];
        [_audioPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
```

Once AVPlayer will have valid file from mURL then it'll call observer with Status ready to play.  " AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay "

```
#pragma Observer for Player status.
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

    if (object == _audioPlayer && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
        if (_audioPlayer.status == AVPlayerStatusFailed) {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayer Failed");

        } else if (_audioPlayer.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay");            
                [_audioPlayer play];

            }

        } else if (_audioPlayer.status == AVPlayerItemStatusUnknown) {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayer Unknown");


        }
        [_audioPlayer removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" context:nil];
    }

}
```

Can you please try with it. and post your comment if we need to handle it  by other way. Also please check the video file is valid and have contents.